# Button not showing up while opening new page (python tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I want to use the listbox in tkinter in order to open a new window with a button, but when I'm pressing a message it only opens the window, without the button.

```
from tkinter import *
from playsound import playsound
import os
# create a window as root using Tk() function
root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
# create a changecolor function
# to change background color of window

def new_win():
    top2 = Toplevel(root)
    top2.geometry('200x200')
    top2.title("display Window")
    # photo2 = PhotoImage(file=r"hearing.png")
    button = Button(text='wtf')

def changecolor(event):
    # get selected list box color item
    new_win()

# create listbox
listbox = Listbox(root , font=('times 20 bold'), height=5,width=10)
# insert color items into listbox
listbox.insert(1, 'first')
listbox.insert(2, 'second')
listbox.insert(3, 'third')
listbox.insert(4, 'forth')
listbox.pack(pady=20)
# bind the click event with listbox and
# call changecolor() function
listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', changecolor)
root.mainloop()
```

Any suggestion would be very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the line 16
`button = Button(text='wtf')`
to

```
button = Button(top2,text='wtf')
button.pack()
```